# HttpWebRequest not sending cookies on POST

Tags: vb.net, iis, post, cookies, httpwebrequest

I’m writing a http module to work as a reverse proxy, i.e. receives a request from a browser, sends it on to the target site, receives a response and sends that back to the browser.

Its all working fine, except for a problem with forwarding cookies from the browser request to the target site on a Post. All headers and form data are correct on the outgoing request, but no cookies are included.

I’ve run fiddler on both the request from the browser to IIS and the outgoing httpwebrequest and proven this to be the case. Running the module in debug shows that the cookies are found in the request from the browser and successfully placed in the cookiecontainer of the httpwebrequest, but they just don’t appear in the actual request sent out.

If I hack (in debug) the outgoing request method to a Get, then they go, but they don’t go for a Post.

I’ve also tracked the request/response from a browser direct to the target site using Fiddler, and the request seems identical in all three cases (browser to target, browser to my IIS module, IIS module to target), except that the IIS module to target omits the cookies.

Here’s the code (VB.Net, and tried in 2.0 and 4.5):

```
' set up the request to the target
Dim reqTarget As System.Net.HttpWebRequest 
reqTarget = CType(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strTargetURL & strTargetPath & qstring), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

' copy relevant info, cookies etc from the application request to the target request
CopyAppRequest(application.Context.Request, reqTarget)

' send the request and get the response
Dim rspTarget As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(reqTarget.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)


Private Sub CopyAppRequest(ByRef reqApp As System.Web.HttpRequest, ByRef reqTarget As System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

    ' copy over the headers
    For Each key As String In reqApp.Headers.AllKeys
        Select Case key
            Case "Host", "Connection", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "Expect",  "Authorization", "If-Modified-Since"
                ' not sure if we need to process these
            Case "Connection"
                reqTarget.Connection = reqApp.Headers(key)
            Case "Content-Type"
                reqTarget.ContentType = reqApp.Headers(key)
            Case "Accept"
                reqTarget.Accept = reqApp.Headers(key)
            Case "Referer"
                reqTarget.Referer = reqApp.Headers(key)
            Case "User-Agent"
                reqTarget.UserAgent = reqApp.Headers(key)
            Case "Cookie"
                ' do nothing, cookies are handled below..
            Case Else
                reqTarget.Headers.Add(key, reqApp.Headers(key)
        End Select
    Next

    reqTarget.Method = reqApp.HttpMethod
    reqTarget.AllowAutoRedirect = False

    If reqTarget.Method = "POST" Then
        reqTarget.ContentLength = reqApp.ContentLength
        Dim datastream() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqApp.Form.ToString)
        reqTarget.ContentLength = datastream.Length
        Dim requestwriter As System.IO.Stream = reqTarget.GetRequestStream
        requestwriter.Write(datastream, 0, datastream.Length)
        requestwriter.Close()
        requestwriter.Dispose()
    End If

    Dim CookieJar As New System.Net.CookieContainer
    reqTarget.CookieContainer = CookieJar

    For Each key As String In reqApp.Cookies.AllKeys
        Dim tgtCookie As New System.Net.Cookie
        With tgtCookie 
            .Name = reqApp.Cookies.Item(key).Name
            .Value = reqApp.Cookies.Item(key).Value
            .Domain = ".domain.com"
            .Path = "/"
            .Expires = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, System.DateTime.Now)
            .HttpOnly = True
      End With
        CookieJar.Add(tgtCookie)
    Next

End Sub
```

Note: the domain I’m trying to reach is in the form abc.domain.com (i.e. it’s a subdomain, and no www), the reason I’ve tried the .domain.com form is that is the form used in the cookies that are received in the response. I’ve also tried other combinations such as abc.domain.com, .abc.domain.com, etc. Also I’ve tried creating a Uri object and using that method to add the cookie into the cookiecontainer.

I’ve tried everything I can think of and can find on forums…. Anyone got any suggestions? I suspect I’ve missed something obvious!

Of course, any other comments on how the code above can be improved will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Since posting this I've ben trying lots of things. One bit that is relevant is when I add this line of code before the GetResponse: Dim strCookie As String = reqTarget.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(reqTarget.RequestUri)  Then strCookie contains the cookie header I expect to see in the request!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue...

I was using Fiddler to see what was going on with http, and Fiddler was correct. However, when I used Wireshark, I found that the http request was being sent earlier than I thought, and only on the Post.

It turned out that the requestwriter.write line caused the http request to be sent, not the GetResponse (as is the case with Get). So, anything I changed in the httpwebrequest after the requestwriter.write didn't get sent.

The fix - I just moved all the header and cookie set up above the requestwriter.write and it all worked.

How frustrating, but at least its fixed now :)

If anyone has any feedback on whether I've got something wrong that's causing this to happen, please let me know.